# How can I replace an Indian passport while residing in USA?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, photography, f1-visas

I’m currently on my F-1 student visa in the US. I am a citizen of India. While traveling to another state, one TSA officer told me to replace it because it has a washed out photo, or I’ll have problems in the future. What are the steps to replace/update it? I don’t want to go back to India, just to replace it. Can I do it while staying in the US?

Comment: Is this the photo on your actual passport that's a problem?  You have only one option - get new photos and a replacement passport.

Comment: If you agree that the photo is not good enough (and remember it was good enough to get into USA before!) then most likely you can get it replaced by an India embassy or consulate in the USA.

Comment: The edit to the question changes its focus completely and makes my answer look idiotic.

Comment: @choster your answer is still correct and still addresses the body of the question.

Comment: Yes. @choster’s answer is correct too. But I found Newton’s to be a complete answer. Thank you to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your passport got damaged because it got wet etc. then you can apply for a new passport using the counselor services of the [Embassy of India](https://www.indianembassy.org/index.php) in the USA.

There is a [passport service](https://www.indianembassy.org/pages.php?id=19) section where you can find information on how to apply for a new/replacement passport while in the US. You will need:

- your recent original indian passport
- US resident status details

Important details:

- apply for the passport on the CKGS website ONLY. Don't apply on the Government of India's website.
- You will be given a temporary number. Do remember to write it down or print it. You can use it to complete your application later on etc.
- You can submit your application via walk-in or mail it to them. Follow the packing details carefully if you choose to mail it.

Please read the [application guide](https://passport.in.ckgs.us/passport-application-guide) once before getting started.

Comment: +1 and I just want to add that these steps are valid for getting a new Indian passport in any non emergency circumstances while in the US such as running out of pages, passport expiring etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't had problems before, the problem might just lie with this particular TSA agent, especially if s/he was one who is unaccustomed to checking passports (which is most of them, outside of major hubs, border areas, college towns, resort areas, and a few other places frequented by international visitors).

Broadly speaking, there is no way to alter any part of any country's passport without replacing the entire passport. There is no way to modify your name, for example, or your sex, even if they have been legally changed, and you can no longer add pages to them. If the photo is faded or has otherwise been damaged, unfortunately, you will need to obtain a new passport.

Comment: The US no longer adds extra pages.

Comment: @phoog Right you are; updated.